# How to echo names of last upload file

Tags: php, sql, html, echo

I was asked that the output file should only output the name and id of the last person who uploaded a file with a specific name. confusing right? even I am confused. so let me give an example

let us say that you have 3 employees registered in your company. lets call them

1. Pikachu,
2. Raichu and
3. Pichu.

Pikachu has 3 files uploaded in the company, Raichu has 2 files uploaded and Pichu has also 2 files uploaded. The files must also be ordered according to employeename(ASC) and filename(DESC). Mine is already in ordered by. This is my only problem. In this case the output should look like this:

*noticed that the employee name and employee id is in the last file uploaded?? does anyone knows how to do that?please i beg you guys to help me out here T-T the task is way too hard and im just a rookie

Im thinking of using 2 tables here. table 1 for the employee id and employee name, table 2 for the file name, etc. so i guess this would also involve 2 while clause. i have the idea but i dont know how to mix them all up.

my code before I edited it like sir vincent look like this:

```
if ($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa' 
   OR $_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
{                                   

  $sql= "select * from gmdc_employee 
         where employee_name like '%$search%' 
         AND employee_name like '$listname%'";
} else {
  $sql = "select b.* from gmdc_user a, gmdc_employee b 
          where a.username = '".$_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()]."' 
          AND a.company_id = b.company_id 
          AND b.employee_name like '$listname%' 
          AND b.employee_name like '%$search%'"; 
}
$query = mysql_query("$sql ORDER BY employee_name,confirmation DESC 
                     ,file_id DESC,file_date DESC 
                      LIMIT $offset,$limit") or die ( mysql_error () );
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
{
  $fgmembersite->HandleError("No file found.");
  return false;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $file_id = $row['file_id'];
  $file_desc = $row['file_description'];
  $file_date = $row['file_date'];
  $file_name = $row['file_name'];
  $file_accs = $row['folder_access'];
  $file_employee  = $row['employee_id'];
  $file_confir = $row['confirmation'];
  $file_ename = ucwords($row['employee_name']);

  $info = pathinfo($file_name);
  $file_ext = $info['extension'];

  echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="subone"><td class="sub" width="100">'.$file_employee.'<br />
        &nbsp;</td>';
  if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
  {
    ?>
    <td class="sub" width="100">
    <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addfile.php?emp=
    <?php echo $file_employee ?>');><?php echo$file_ename?></a>
    <br />&nbsp;</td>
    <?php
  } else {
    echo '<td class="sub" width="182">'.$file_ename.'<br />&nbsp;</td>';
  }
  echo'<td  class="sub" width="218">
       <a href="'.$file_accs.$file_name.'" target="_blank" 
        style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$file_desc.'</a>
       <br />&nbsp;</td><td  class="sub" width="100">
      '.date('M d, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($file_date,5,2)
       ,substr($file_date,8,2),substr($file_date,0,4))).'
       <br />&nbsp;</td><td  class="sub" width="100">'.$file_confir.'
       <br />&nbsp;</td>';

  if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
  {
    if($file_confir == 'Pending' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
    {
      if(isset($_GET['id']))
      {
        $fgmembersite->Delete_Db($_GET['id']);
      }
      echo '<td  class="sub" width="100">
            <a href="index.php?id='.$file_id.'">Delete</a>
            <br />&nbsp;</td>';
    }
  }
  else if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
  {
    if($file_confir == 'Pending')
      {
        if(isset($_GET['yes']))
        {
          $fgmembersite->UpdateYesDB($_GET['yes']);
          //echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['no']))
        {
          $fgmembersite->UpdateNoDB($_GET['no']);
          //echo "<script>location.reload();</script>";
        }
        if (!isset($_GET['offset'])) {
          $prevoffset = 0;
        } else {
          $prevoffset = $_GET['offset'];
          echo'<td  class="sub" width="100">
          <a href="index.php?offset='.$prevoffset.'&searchfile='.$search.'
           &namelist='.$listname.'&yes='.$file_id.'">Approve</a>
           //there's a link here<br /><br />
           <a href="index.php?offset='.$prevoffset.'&searchfile='.$search.'
            &namelist='.$listname.'&no='.$file_id.'">NotApprove</a>
            //there's a link here
            &nbsp;</td> ';
      }
    }
  }?>
```

Just ignore every `if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')` and whatever, this is for different output since my file can be logged into by 3 different users. SA(programmers), admin(the approver of the file uploaded), and user(company). There are TD and TR there as well, I don't know why wont it appear here.

output looked like this:

```
employee_id  +   employee_name  +  file_name
3            |   pichu          |  file6
3            |   pichu          |  file1
1            |   pikachu        |  file7
1            |   pikachu        |  file4
1            |   pikachi        |  file3
2            |   raichu         |  file8
2            |   raichu         |  file5
2            |   raichu         |  file2
```

and I want my output to be like this:

```
***OUTPUT***

**employee_id        employee_name              file_name**
    3                      pichu                        file6
                                                        file1
    1                     pikachu                       file7
                                                        file4
                                                        file3
    2                     raichu                        file5
                                                        file2
```

for example that raichu uploaded another file, the output should now look like this:

***OUTPUT***

```
**employee_id        employee_name            file_name**
    3                      pichu                      file6
                                                      file1
    1                      pikachu                    file7
                                                      file4
                                                      file3
    2                      raichu                     file8
                                                      file5
                                                      file2
```

Comment: @ace , sir i forgot to mention here in my new post what <<employee_name like '%$search%' AND employee_name like '$listname%'>> is for, they are used for my A-Z pagelist and for my search button. all is working properly. the limit and offset i used for my page number located below the table that i did not include in this table code above :)

Comment: Its been a long time since I'm not doing an application with php so I little forgot it. Anyway looking at your 2nd while which you have a $sql2, about the `where clause` its kinda bit wrong. Uhm if the result of $file_employee is an array, I guess its better it is inside an `IN`. Did you get any mysql_error? Try to check first the query before printing the output.

Comment: actually,this page did not input all the correct codes that i have,i tried editing it but when i checked the code, its correct, then post it again, the same missing codes are there.

Comment: @ace and i tried your`code` SELECT  e.employee_id as employee_id,           
        e.employee_name as employee_name,
        f.file_description as file_description,
        f.file_date as file_date,
        f.confirmation as confirmation
  FROM gmdc_user e                              
 INNER JOIN gmdc_employee f                               
    ON e.employee_id = f.employee_id
 ORDER BY e.employee_name, f.confirmation DESC,f.file_id DESC, f.file_date DESC <<i changed it a bit but only the 1st name echoed in my myphpadmin

Comment: Hmm?? try first to use simple join. Like `SELECT * FROM gmdc_user gu INNER JOIN gmdc_employee ge ON gu.employee_id = ge.employee_id`. And read about mysql join http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @ace i edited my post and changed it with the original code i used to have that made the same output as yours, so if the output looks like the one's like yours, where should i put these codes of yours with the PHP on it? i think thats my key in achieving my goal :)

Comment: @ace i thinks your `code` SELECT  e.employee_id as employee_id,           
        e.employee_name as employee_name,
        f.file_description as file_description,
        f.file_date as file_date,
        f.confirmation as confirmation
  FROM gmdc_user e                              
 INNER JOIN gmdc_employee f                               
    ON e.employee_id = f.employee_id
 ORDER BY e.employee_name, f.confirmation DESC,f.file_id DESC, f.file_date DESC `code` works better than the one listed above. i tried in at myphpadmin

Comment: Do the same thing as what I did, if the problem is printing the a repeated field. Of course you need declare a variable first before the `while` then inside the while to check if the `employee_id` is same with the current. As with my code I use ternary operator, this same with `if else` then follow the rest. And which are not appearing on you `TD` and `TR`?

Comment: @ace yes, the <td> <tr> are not appearing in my post. im worried some might e confused with it. anyway i'll try to bring back my old code and try to combine it with yours. i guess i'll update you of the possible result :)

Comment: OK please do, also check the source code in the browser, better to use the firebug or chrome developer tools. May not only the contents of `TD` or `TR` missing also the element itself. If you get the result you wanted using the query then you probably output it. Just play around on the code.

Comment: @ace, i tried putting your **
$emp_id = "";     //This will be use to remove employee_id if its already echoed.
$emp_name = "";   //This will be use to remove employee_name if its already echoed.
** and your **   $emp_id = $emp_id == $row['employee_id'] ? "" : $row['employee_id']
    $emp_name = $emp_name == $row['employee_name'] ? "" : $row['employee_name'];
** in my code.but there aren't any changes :(

Comment: really? anyway finally you fixed it, goodluck with the rest.

Comment: @Misa - No need to edit the title. Selecting an answer is sufficient to indicate that the question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Vincent table structure will likely solve your problem. And to get the result you wanted, you can use single query using join for the two table. So there's no need to use two query.

```
SELECT  e.employee_id as employee_id,            //Display column for employee_id
        e.employee_name as employee_name,        
        f.file_name as file_name
  FROM employee e                                // The e is an alias for table
 INNER JOIN file f                               // The inner join will return all the rows which have same employee_id on both table 
    ON e.employee_id = f.employee_id
 ORDER BY e.employee_name, f.file_name DESC;     // Order of the result default is ASC
```

**UPDATE**

I assume you have two tables and the structure is same with Vincent. Now This query will get the data on two tables. The join part here is that, when an `employee_id`  on `employee table` has a same `employee_id` on the `file table`, this will return a row. Please see [mysql join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for more information. Then the order `e.employee_id` is the employee_id on `employee` table, since there's no order specified it will use the default which is `ascending`.

Then output of the above query could be the below code.

```
employee_id  +   employee_name  +  file_name
3            |   pichu          |  file6
3            |   pichu          |  file1
1            |   pikachu        |  file7
1            |   pikachu        |  file4
1            |   pikachi        |  file3
2            |   raichu         |  file8
2            |   raichu         |  file5
2            |   raichu         |  file2
```

You will notice that employee_id and employee_name is repeated. This is because the query include all the columns value in a row that specified in `SELECT column_name`. You can filter the duplicate value in your php, specially if you will store it first in an object rather than directly printing it.

**PHP**

```
$query = $see_the_query_above;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db));
$emp_id = "";     //This will be use to remove employee_id if its already echoed.
$emp_name = "";   //This will be use to remove employee_name if its already echoed.

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>employee_id</th><th>employee_name</th><th>file_name</th></tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Check $emp_id and $emp_name if same with the current, if same just print nothing or space else replace it with new.
    $emp_id = $emp_id == $row['employee_id'] ? "" : $row['employee_id']
    $emp_name = $emp_name == $row['employee_name'] ? "" : $row['employee_name'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$emp_id.'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$emp_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['file_name'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: im not familiar with this codes but these also looks pretty helpful, would you mind explaining it to me and where should i put it?

Comment: What is your current code? is it same with Vincent 2nd post? OK, if you know how to output a simple query then this is the same things. I'll wait for your answer to this so I can explain more details. Oops, I see you have commented on Vincent code, I'll try to explain it.

Comment: yes its almost the same as sir vincent's code, i also used only 1 table in this set of codes but im a bit confused in the  echo '<td>';
part, because you see, in my 2nd while, it will output 4 different <td>, soo im not sure how should i arrange it like the ones that sir vincent used

Comment: Actually Vincent code already arrange things in proper order. What result did you get, after you use his code? and also check first you table contents on the database, if it actually have the value you wanted.

Comment: @ace do i also have to echo the <td> separately? cant i just use one echo instead? i could post a copy of my code here if you want to sir :)

Comment: Please do. I also updated my post, but I guess this is more tricky to you, cause I'm bad on how to explain it :)

Comment: i kinda get it sir @ace and im currently studying it now, although im a bit confused on why is there only one table and one while, my header <th> part is also located above or before the $sql statement select but is still working. i hope you could try connecting the changes with the codes i used that i posted above. :)

Comment: actually before i edited my code like the one's of sir @vincent, my code's output look like the 2nd <pre> (which is the output) you inserted

Comment: So you actually get the result you wanted, but just have some extra value. I guess you can refer to my sample code to get rid of it. Then about one table and one while, sorry but its not clear to me. Better read the mysql join.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like not that hard.

TABLE `employee`:
this table may have two fields(in the simplest way): employee_id, employee_name

TABLE `file`:
this table may have three fields: file_id, employee_id(this is a foreign key), file_name

when the file is uploaded, change its name to this format: "file" + file_id

therefor, we have:

TABLE `employee`:

```
employee_id  |  employee_name
-----------------------------
1            |  pikachu
2            |  raichu
3            |  pichu
```

TABLE `file`:

```
file_id  |  employee_id  |  file_name
-------------------------------------
1        |  3            |  file1
2        |  2            |  file2
3        |  1            |  file3
4        |  1            |  file4
5        |  2            |  file5
6        |  3            |  file6
7        |  1            |  file7
8        |  2            |  file8
```

then it is really easy to make them all up, what do you think?

Comment: thank you for your reply and i get your logic sir, but that is not the output that i am expecting to be :( the output should look like something above.

Comment: if you noticed sir, file 1 is also under the employee_name pikachu, but the name and id of file 1 did not output itself.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you use MySQL and assuming we have establish a database connection using a reference $db:

```
$query = 'SELECT employee_id, employee_name FROM `employee` ORDER BY employee_name ASC';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db));

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>employee_id</th><th>employee_name</th><th>file_name</th></tr>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['employee_id'].'<td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['employee_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>';

    $query2 = 'SELECT file_name FROM `file` WHERE employee_id='.$row['employee_id'].' ORDER BY file_id DESC';
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error($db));

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        echo $row2['file_name'].'<br />';
    }

    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

this piece of code will work.

Comment: thats what i did sir vincent :( but my file_name did not echoed for some unknown reason :( instead there's a message above the table "no file found" which is my error tracker <pre> if(!$result1 || mysql_num_rows($result1) <= 0)
        {
         $fgmembersite->HandleError("No file found.");
         return false;
        } </pre> written befor my while clause